# To move between windows in Screen by combine keys

Tags: gnu-screen

How to bind following key to move between windows in gnu screen ?

Ctrl+Shirt+h: move to prev window
 Ctrl+Shirt+l: move to next window

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try to write below setting to your .screenrc.(and restart screen)

- `bind ^H prev` to bind Ctrl+H(Shift+h) as `prev`
- `bind ^L next` to bind Ctrl+L(Shift+l) as `next`

or execute screen command on your running screen process.

- `C-a` `:bind ^H prev`
- `C-a` `:bind ^L next`